# Outdated CloudFormation schemas for IntelliJ/WebStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, yaml, schema, webstorm

I am getting schema validation warnings "Value should be one of" when having YAML file opened with CloudFormation template. It seems that IntelliJ/WebStorm are validating YAML against remote JSON schemas if available, in this case it seems to be: https://www.schemastore.org/json/ (as stated here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/yaml.html#remote_json)

But for some reason as simple type as CloudFront distribution does not validate:
`Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution` but for example `Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition` is accepted fine. For me it looks like that https://www.schemastore.org/json/ should be up to date. Anyone else experiencing similar issues?

I also tried this plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7371-aws-cloudformation, but that doesnt seem to even work when YAML validation by JSON schema is disabled:
[image: yaml-validation]

Comment: Same problem, were you able to resolve it?

Comment: Didn't manage to solve. I started actually using Visual Studio Code